# How to retrieve values from configuration file for Shell Scripts ( Without the knowledge of Keys )

Tags: linux, bash, shell

As per my scenario, Need to collect values from configuration files. But need to access values from the configuration files without specifying the keys.

By the `source command` I have done it to retrieve values by the following

**Configuration.conf**

> export Name=value
>
> export Age=value
>
> export Address=value

**Script.sh**

```
source Configuration.conf

echo $Name
echo $Age
echo $Address
```

By the above way I could access the values from the configuration files.

---

**I would like access the values without using the key of the configuration files.**

In my above scenario, Key will be changing in any form (But values are going to be similar as well my logic). At the script I have to read the values without knowing the Key name. something like the following.

```
source Configuration.conf
while [ $1 ] // Here 1 is representing the first Key of the configuration file. 
do
//My Logics
done
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The example that you give, `while [ $1 ]` would do the same regardless of what the parameter is.  It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @devnull : Really sorry for putting up question in a confusing way. Now I have changed it. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the configuration file only contains var=value declarations with each declaration occupying a single line.

```
configfile=./Configuration.conf

. "$configfile"

declare -A configlist

while IFS='=' read -r key val ; do

  # skip empty / commented lines and obviously invalid input
  [[ $key =~ ^[[:space:]]*[_[:alpha:]] ]] || continue

  # Stripping up to the last space in $key removes "export".
  # Using eval to approximate the shell's handling of lines like this:
  #    var="some thing with spaces" # and a trailing comment.
  eval "configlist[${key##* }]=$val"

done < "$configfile"

# The keys are "${!configlist[@]}", the values are "${configlist[@]}"
#
#for key in "${!configlist[@]}" ; do
#  printf '"%s" = "%s"\n' "$key" "${configlist[$key]}"
#done

for value in "${configlist[@]}" ; do
  : your logic goes here
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I would parse the config file using `sed` and `cut`. Like this:

```
sed -n 's/export//p' conf.sh | while read expression ; do 
    key=$(cut -d= -f1 <<< "$expression")
    value=$(cut -d= -f2 <<< "$expression")

    # your logic comes here ...
    echo "$key -> $value"
done
```

Ouput:

```
Name -> value
Age -> value
Address -> value
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the keys from the conf file with grep. Get the values using [variable indirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
keys=( $(grep -oP '\w+(?==)' conf.conf) )
for (( i=0; i < ${#keys[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${keys[i]}"
done
echo
source conf.conf
for var in "${keys[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t=> %s\n" "$var" "${!var}"
done
```

```
0   Name
1   Age
2   Address

Name    => name_value
Age     => age_value
Address => addr_value
```

Comment: It is working fine. Thank you so much for that. Having doubt in your code. Please share me your knowledge. **without using source command your code is working fine. How it is possible ?**  **In which way you are storing the keys and values in memory**

Comment: You must have previously sourced the conf file in your current shell. Launch a new shell and try again